# Select into table : will it work for inserting data into existing table?

Tags: sql-server

I have this table called `test`:

```
LoadID  name    comment
------------------------
1234    mobeen  NULL
```

and this table called `temp`:

```
LoadId      comments
--------------------------------
1234        abc,abcdef,abcdefg
12345       abcdefgadsf
28366356    test,testing
```

What I am trying to do is to insert the comments from the `temp` table into the `test` table into the `comment` column, where the `LoadID` of the first table matches the `LoadID` in the second table.

I tried this code

```
INSERT INTO [test] (comment)
    SELECT comments
    FROM temp 
    INNER JOIN [test] ON temp.LoadID = [test].LoadID
    WHERE [test].LoadID IS NOT NULL;
```

But all I am getting is:

```
LoadID  name    comment
-------------------------------------
1234    mobeen  NULL
NULL    NULL    abc,abcdef,abcdefg
```

while I want the output to be like this table

```
LoadID  name    comment
-------------------------------------
1234    mobeen  abc,abcdef,abcdefg
```

Comment: Well....your insert statement is only inserting into the comment column. What do you expect to happen? If you want to change the value of an existing row you would use UPDATE. If you want all the columns in a newly inserted row to have values you have to insert into those columns.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you want to do something like this. Please note that checking for LoadID not being NULL is pointless. You have an inner join so it can't possibly be NULL.

```
update t
set comment = t.comments
from temp tmp
join test t on t.LoadID = tmp.LoadID
--where t.LoadID is not null
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work for me. There is some slight changes in the query. temp is not a table in the database but a result of a subquery. But it should not make much difference I guess. 
It looks like this:
UPDATE T
SET comment = 
(SELECT comments
FROM (SELECT l.LoadId,
STUFF( (SELECT ',' + coment 
FROM TB_SOT_Comment c2
WHERE c2.LoadID = l.LoadId
FOR XML PATH ('')
 ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as comments
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT LoadId FROM TB_SOT_Comment)l) as temp)
join temp as x on x.LoadId = t.LoadId
But when I do this it does not recognize temp as an object

Comment: No idea what that update is in your comment but wow...how many select statement do you need? And the FOR XML was not in your original question. Perhaps you should share ALL of the details? This is actually quite easy and you are very close but I can't help you because there are not enough details.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer was right but was updating temp table.

```
update t 
    set comment = x.comments
    from test as t 
    inner join @temp x on x.LoadId = t.LoadId;
```